# Chemfig: scheme vertical align

Tags: vertical-alignment, chemfig, chemistry

How can I vertical align this scheme to the same bottom line?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin=15mm,
  bindingoffset=2mm,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\newcommand{\br}{\\ \vspace{5pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\schemestart
\chemfig{R-C(-[2]O^{\oplus}(-[2]R')(-[4]H))(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)(-[0]H)}
\arrow(.-1--){->[{-}\chemfig{H^+}]}[,1.5]
\chemname{\chemfig{R-C(-[2]{\color{red}O}|{\color{red}R'})(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)(-[0]H)}}{Etere}
\schemestop
\chemnameinit{}
\end{figure}

\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330375/124842

Comment: Putting a `figure` inside a `flushleft` environment is just wrong. `\begin{figure} \raggedright ... \end{figure}` would be the right thing instead…

Comment: I'm also wondering why you're loading both `chemformula` *and* `mhchem`? Using both `\ch{...}` *and* `\ce{...}` will only produce visually inconsistent results…

Comment: `\newcommand{\br}{\\ \vspace{5pt}}` doesn't look right, either: you'll either want `\newcommand{\br}{\\[5pt]}` or `\newcommand{\br}{\par\vspace{5pt}}`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by @Bobyandbob, this is a duplicate of [tex.stackexchange.com/a/330375/124842](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330359).

The baseline of each molecule is the first atom, in this case R. The arrow needs to be anchored to that baseline to get a suitable vertical alignment. This is done using `\arrow{base east --.base west)`. Since the arrow then sits directly on the baseline, it is more pleasing to apply a small vertical shift `[3pt]` to move the arrow slightly upwards, without affecting the baseline alignment of the molecules.

This is the result:
[image]

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin=15mm,
  bindingoffset=2mm,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\newcommand{\br}{\\ \vspace{5pt}}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
\chemfig{R-C(-[2]O^{\oplus}(-[2]R')(-[4]H))(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)(-[0]H)}
\arrow(.base east--.base west){->[$-\chemfig{H^+}$][][3pt]}
\chemname{\chemfig{R-C(-[2]{\color{red}O}|{\color{red}R'})(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)(-[0]H)}}{Etere}
\schemestop
\chemnameinit{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you mind removing the `flushleft` environment? Putting a `figure` inside is just wrong. `\begin{figure} \raggedright ... \end{figure}` would be the right thing instead

Comment: Instead of `->[{-}\chemfig{H^+}]` it should probably be `->[$-\chemfig{H^+}$]`